# Fish Shell: Install a custom theme from repository

Tags: linux, shell, fish

I like the [chain theme](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/theme-chain) for the fish shell and I've made small custom modifications that I keep in a forked repository.

How can I install the theme from my repository?

I've add the repository with

```sh
omf repo add <url>
```

But when I try to install the theme using `omf install chain` the official theme gets installed. If I try `omf install <url>`, then it returns a `successfully installed` message but I cannot find my theme installed under the `.local/share/omf` folder.